# Set different expanded title and collapsed title for CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Currently we can set only one title using the setTitle() method. Is there a way to achieve something like this:

In expanded mode:

[image: CollapsingToolbarLayout expanded title]

In collapsed mode:

[image: CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsed title]

(Please ignore my poor Paint skills.)

Comment: No you can not set another title in collapsingtoolbarlayout in design support library but you can set gravity in both mode differently.

Comment: @AshishKumarAgrawal thanks. Tried playing with the title gravity methods, but it's not possible with that.